# Best way to create new React component using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app`. Is there a command to create a component to scaffold the files.

Right now I am manually creating the files. Say if the component name is `Button`, I create a folder named Button inside the component folder and then create `Button.js` and `Button.css` files.

Is there any CLI commands to do this using create-react-app? I know there is a way to do this Angular CLI but don't know anything with React CLI.

Comment: I appreciate this question. Feels like an extension that would save me time. I'm about to create 10 components and the boiler plate code is the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another way is to create files manually and use snippets to generate the code.

For example, take a look at this [JavaScript/React VS Code extension](https://github.com/dsznajder/vscode-es7-javascript-react-snippets#rcredux). You can also create your own snippets or find other extensions if you were interested.

Comment: Does this create a component ?

Comment: Yes, for example type `rcc` and hit tab to create a basic React component.

Comment: We'll still have to create the files manually. The should be something like Angular's ng generate command or utility.

Comment: IDE specific solutions are only useful for people using that IDE.  Also the plugin doesn't scaffold a component like the poster wants - (A component may consist of multiple files like Component.spec.js, Component.less, Component.js) it's not just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 83):

You may use directly without installing the [generate-react-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-react-cli)

```
npx generate-react-cli component MyComponent
```

Which will install a component based on your project preferences (ex: typescript, scss, etc..).

A file called `generate-react-cli.json` will be created where all the settings will be stored for future use.

Comment: As a side note, the first time you run this command (must be on root folder), it'll prompt for several configs (e.g do you use typescript, css modules, do you want tests files, lazy load, etc).

Comment: @phantomCoder this solution is far more complete than the others, and thus should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 9):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-react-component for this,

this will help you to create state and stateless component also known as functional and class components.

Answer (score 2):

Two Easy Ways to create Components in React:

1.) With CLI
npx generate-react-cli component Box

2.) Install this [Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) for VS code.
Create a file name with component.js manually and just type this command **rafce**  and press the tab. You will get the below code automatically.

```
import React from 'react'
const HeaderComponent = () => {
  return (
    <span>HeaderComponent</span>
  )
}
export default HeaderComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of the recent projects I used [Plop JS](https://plopjs.com/documentation/#getting-started). Its very useful to generate files with same set of code.

> Plop is what I like to call a "micro-generator framework." Now, I call it that because it is a small tool that gives you a simple way to generate code or any other type of flat text files in a consistent way. You see, we all create structures and patterns in our code (routes, controllers, components, helpers, etc). These patterns change and improve over time so when you need to create a NEW insert-name-of-pattern-here, it's not always easy to locate the files in your codebase that represent the current "best practice." That's where plop saves you. With plop, you have your "best practice" method of creating any given pattern in CODE. Code that can easily be run from the terminal by typing plop. Not only does this save you from hunting around in your codebase for the right files to copy, but it also turns "the right way" into "the easiest way" to make new files.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `react-component` template from `templates`.

https://marcellino-ornelas.github.io/templates/docs/main/templates/react-component

Supports: typescript, storybook, multiple css languages, and more!

Want more? Need it to fit your code better? use the `copy` command and change it to how you want

Feedback or contributions are welcome!